# What is the keyboard shortcut for "Refresh sbt project" in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the "Refresh sbt project" button in the Build tab of IntelliJ IDEA?

It doesn't show up in search results in "Keymap" or Mac OS' "Help" menubar item.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you rebind "Refresh all external projects" (under "External Build Systems" in "Keymap") it'll refresh.

But it may be that just binding "Refresh external project" is sufficient.